# How to call javascript function (with changing body) from UpdatePanel callback?

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, updatepanel

I'm updating div by injecting there JavaScript  function. I'm using UpdatePanel. 
The problem is that body of this JS function changes. Every time user clicks button then new JS function (the function name is always the same) is placed into the same div but with different body. There reason for this changing content of the function body is new data.

The result for me is that when I call this function I have executed always first function which was in that div. The content of div changes - I've checked.

I have tried:

1. Sys.Application.add_load(GetMyChart)
2. pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler)
3. ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
4. Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
5. Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="chart1" runat="server" >
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function GetMyChart() { alert("wow!"); }
                        </script>
                    </div>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="old text"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            GetMyChart(); 
        }
    </script>


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.InnerHtml = GetChartFunction();
        }
```

In code presented here I always get alert. 
My goal is to call GetMyChart function which will be returned by GetChartFunction() and I need to call it just after update.

Comment: What does `GetChartFunction()` create? Is it a script block that defines a new `GetMyChart` function? If JavaScript has already defined a function with that name, it's unclear whether defining a new function with the same name will replace the older function. Could you generate a distinct name instead and have the emitted script block call the function instead of using `add_endRequest`?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () { PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MYFUNCTION); });` should run everytime the update panel is updated?

Comment: @Jacob, GetChartFunction() returns `<script type="text/javascript">
                            function GetMyChart() { //changing_body }
                        </script>`

Comment: @Jacob, even if I give there distinct name then how to call this function?  this: `<script type="text/javascript"> function XYZ() { //changing_body } XYZ();</script>` won't work. and if I call `XYZ();` in `add_endRequest` then I will have an error. `XYZ is not defined`

Comment: @EGC, I don't want to use jQuery or any other external library.

Comment: Maybe let's try to simplify this. let's asume there is no `GetMyChart` function defined at the beginning. User clicks button and then `GetMyChart` is placed into `div`. how to call this function which haven't existed before in code?

Comment: Wow people are still using updatepanels in 2019. These were only invented as a nasty MS hack because they couldn't do ajax in webforms

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not working, because you returned and assign the `<script type="text/javascript"> function XYZ() { //changing_body } XYZ();</script>` string into a `chart1` div's inner HTML, which does not mean that it would create the new `<script>` tag with function override.

In short, the returned value is treated like a normal string of characters, and it is not correct way of adding new elements to DOM tree.

Furthermore, I was able to reproduce it without using .Net, in native JavaScript, and here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qt1v6mof/

In order to get the expected effect, you should definitely use the document's [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) function in order to create a real `<script>` tag element, and then use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to replace a current div's `innerHTML` content, like in below code and example:

```html
<div id="chart">
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var getMyChart = function() { alert("wow!"); }
  </script>
</div>

<button id="changeBtn">Change getMyChart's body</button>
<button id="callEndRequest">Call endRequestHandler</button>
```

```js
function change() {
    var newScript = document.createElement('script'),
    chartElem = document.getElementById('chart')

  chartElem.innerHTML = ''
  newScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  newScript.innerHTML = 'getMyChart = function() { alert("new body");}'

  chartElem.appendChild(newScript)
}

function endRequestHandler () {
    getMyChart()
}

changeBtn.onclick = change
callEndRequest.onclick = endRequestHandler

getMyChart()
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/9mdeoLb2/

Hope it will help
 you.
Kind regards!